# How to compare 2 dataframe without comparing null values in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1:
   a  b   c
0  1  2   6
1  2  3   7
2  3  4   8
3  4  5   9
4  5  6  10

df2:
     a    b     c
0  NaN  NaN   NaN
1  1.0  NaN   NaN
2  2.0  2.0   NaN
3  4.0  3.0   NaN
4  6.0  6.0  11.0
```

When I trying to do df1 > df2, the output is:

```
In [150]:df1 > df2
Out[150]: 
       a      b      c
0  False  False  False
1   True  False  False
2   True   True  False
3  False   True  False
4  False  False  False
```

**But what I expect is like this:**

```
       a      b      c
0    NaN    NaN    NaN
1   True    NaN    NaN
2   True   True    NaN
3  False   True    NaN
4  False  False  False
```

So, how should I do to compare 2 df and keep the null to null?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try:

```
df1.gt(df2).astype(str).mask(df2.isnull())
```

Output:

```
       a      b      c
0    NaN    NaN    NaN
1   True    NaN    NaN
2   True   True    NaN
3  False   True    NaN
4  False  False  False
```

You could try, but the way pandas changes the dtype of any series with a null to float dtype you will get the following:

```
df1.gt(df2).mask(df2.isnull())
```

Output:

```
     a    b    c
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  NaN  NaN
2  1.0  1.0  NaN
3  0.0  1.0  NaN
4  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: I guess you want to do `df1.gt(df2).mask(df1.isnull() | df2.isnull())`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Its working and really fast! Really learned a lot!